# Add URL to sitemap to be available in the future

Tags: sitemap

I generate automatically the sitemap.xml on publish of content on my website, however some of the content will be publish starting from an specific date and time.

Is there any tag that I can add to a sitemap or any other way to cater for this? so that the google/bing... bots would know to only index the content if the date is greater than 'now'.

I know that I could use a task scheduler to update the sitemap file when the content publish date is reached but I was trying to avoid that solution.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could set the "last-modified" attribute to the date and time in the future when it will be published.

You can read up on the [supported attributes](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) here.

Search engines don't give much weight to sitemap.xml files compared to the actual structure of your site as visible to a human so your time is almost certainly better spent on something else.